# re-program back-key S Advance

Tags: samsung, touchscreen, buttons, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

I've replaced the screen of my S Advance, but now the back-key doesn't work anymore so that's really frustrating.. I'm wondering if it's possible to program the menu-key as back-key. It is not a software bug because I just accidentally teared a flex cable partially.. I hope it's possible, and if not, what would be the best choice for an on-screen buttons app?
Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Like changing key values in /system/usr/layout/generic.kl or something. It's possible to disable them there, so maybe it's possible to change their values or would that mess up my phone?
2nd EDIT: I switched the actions 'BACK'and 'MENU' from key values 139 and 158 in Generic.kl and now the menu-key functions as back-key.. question solved within half an hour.. better do some more research next time haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remap hardware buttons without root, but if you don't want to root your phone there are some [soft key apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.swkey.nonroot) which "work" (they look bad to me, but if they are satisfactory I guess it would work). For how to do remapping or use better soft keys look below:

The first step in this process will be of course to [root](http://androidxda.com/samsung-galaxy-s-advance-i9070) you phone (the linked instructions are just one I found on Google, feel free to look for others).

From here you have two options, either use soft keys or remap your hardware keys.

Soft Keys:

-You can either grab an app to do this for you, or install a custom ROM (for example CyanogenMod) that has the feature built in. Just google "android soft keys" for some app options.

Hardware Keys: [ButtonRemaper](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=850464)

Look for hardware key remapping on Google for more options.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help! i'm rooted already and i've modified build.prop to show softkeys(added line:qemu.hw.mainnkeys=0), which work, but i'm curious if it's possible to change the mapping of my home and menu button. Your HWkeys solution look like a good one so i'm gonna try that. hope it works..